# MulterError: Unexpected field when i need to upload multiple file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

i want uplaod tow file in one request in nodejs and i using the moulter for this work .

this is my request in postman :

[image]

and i using the multer in routing :

```
router.post(
  "/Create",
  UploadProfileHandler.single("signerProfile"),
  UploadPosterHandler.single("signerPoster"),
  SignerValidation.CreateHandle(),
  SignerController.CreateSigner
);
```

and this isnto the multer :

`signer Profile Multer :`

```
const multer = require("multer");
const fs = require("fs");
const mkdirp = require("mkdirp");
const path = require("path");

const GetDirectory = () => {
  let year = new Date().getFullYear();
  let month = new Date().getMonth();
  let day = new Date().getDay();
  return `src/public/uploads/signer/profile/${year}/${month}/${day}`;
};

const SignerStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    console.log(file,req.body)
    let dir = GetDirectory();
    mkdirp(dir).then((made) => {
      cb(null, dir);
    });
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    let fileName = GetDirectory() + "/" + file.originalname;
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  },
});

const UploadSigner = multer({
  storage: SignerStorage,
});

module.exports = UploadSigner;
```

and this is `singer  Poster Multer :`

```
    const multer = require("multer");
const fs = require("fs");
const mkdirp = require("mkdirp");
const path = require("path");

const GetDirectory = () => {
  let year = new Date().getFullYear();
  let month = new Date().getMonth();
  let day = new Date().getDay();
  return `src/public/uploads/signer/poster/${year}/${month}/${day}`;
};

const SignerStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    let dir = GetDirectory();
    mkdirp(dir).then((made) => {
      cb(null, dir);
    });
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    let fileName = GetDirectory() + "/" + file.originalname;
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  },
});

const UploadSigner = multer({
  storage: SignerStorage,
});

module.exports = UploadSigner;
```

But when I want to upload both files at the same time it show me this error :

> MulterError: Unexpected field
> at wrappedFileFilter (F:\Projects\Nodejs\SalesSignal\node_modules\multer\index.js:40:19)
> at Busboy. (F:\Projects\Nodejs\SalesSignal\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:114:7)
> at Busboy.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at Busboy.emit (F:\Projects\Nodejs\SalesSignal\node_modules\busboy\lib\main.js:38:33)
> at PartStream. (F:\Projects\Nodejs\SalesSignal\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:213:13)
> at PartStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at HeaderParser. (F:\Projects\Nodejs\SalesSignal\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:51:16)
> at HeaderParser.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at SBMH.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at SBMH._sbmh_feed (F:\Projects\Nodejs\SalesSignal\node_modules\streamsearch\lib\sbmh.js:159:14)
> at SBMH.push (F:\Projects\Nodejs\SalesSignal\node_modules\streamsearch\lib\sbmh.js:56:14)
> at HeaderParser.push (F:\Projects\Nodejs\SalesSignal\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:46:19)
> at Dicer._oninfo (F:\Projects\Nodejs\SalesSignal\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:197:25)
> at SBMH. (F:\Projects\Nodejs\SalesSignal\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:127:10)

**whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ???**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle multiple fields you cannot call the `.single()` middleware multiple times, instead you should use `.array()` or [`.fields()`](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#fields). Here's an example how you would use the latter:

```
app.post("/upload", upload.fields([
    {name: 'signerPoster'},
    {name: 'signerProfile'}
]), (req, res) => {
   // do something with req.files and req.body
});
```

The uploaded files will be populated under `req.files.signerPoster` and `req.files.signerProfile` and `req.body` will contain the text-based fields.